# Publicacion de una prueba de MVC ASP.NET Super Novato

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, servidor

Bueno soy  super novato en programacion. Estoy intentando adentrarme. Vengo de delphi haciendo pabadas desktop, moviendo progressbar y dando nombre a los botones y esas cosas jaja.

**Mi consulta es la siguiente:**
Quiero desplegar una pequeña prueba de una **MVC** super básica que hice en **ASP.NET** como para entender conceptos.
La voy a querer desplegar en una maquina virtual de Windows posteriormente como para ir practicando.

Estaba queriendo cambiar el puerto y la dirección por donde accedo. Puesto que cuando ejecuto, queda escuchando en http://localhost

Ahora leyendo por ahí, veo que algunos instalan el servicio **IIS**, o lo configuran con **apache** o **kestrel**, (que son servidores http segun se de toda la vida, o eso creo.)

**PREGUNTA:**

Cuando yo compilo con **ASP.NET** (usando net 7) acaso no se crea un servidor propio ?

Necesito instalar algo mas para correr el servidor ?(además del **NET RUNTIME**).

Lo basico que hice fue publicar mi proyecto desde vsCode con :

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained --output C:\Users\destl\Desktop\PruebaMVC
```

Entiendo que publicarlo de esta manera, crea el ejecutable dentro de mi carpeta PruebaMVC en windows. Esto posteriormente quiero hacerlo en la maquina virtual.

**NOTA:** Tenia entendido que ASP crea un servidor propio y podría correrlo independiente. O quizá sigo confundido. Gracias

**OTRA NOTA** : Hacer HTML css y javascript o base de datos medianamente basico es tranquilo. Pero esto de la creacion de API, y controladores es terrible. Me encontré con una pared inmensa.

Comment: Elije uno al frente: (Internet Information Services || Apache || NginX) y detrás llamará a Kestrel. Revisa la documentación oficial, ahí está el paso a paso detallado. Si quieres aprender MVC tal cual, este workshop te puede ser de utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY&list=PL-_pdwtmHN2TcXVCoDc0qSqzwRFgJarO_&index=14 aunque es con `net framework`, los conceptos se mantienen y algunas cosas también. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te respondo en orden:

> Cuando yo compilo con ASP.NET (usando net 7) acaso no se crea un
> servidor propio ?

Si, se llama Kestrel y basta con ejecutar el .exe en windows para tener un aplicación corriendo.

La configuración para kestrel ha variado de versión en versión de .net, así mucho ojo con los ejemplos que encuentras en internet.

---

> Necesito instalar algo mas para correr el servidor ?(además del NET
> RUNTIME).

No, al menos que uses referencias a librerías COM (tecnología antigua). Y según como realices el `publish` tampoco puede ser necesario instalar el runtime, ya que el comando `--self-contained true` hace que la aplicación cuente con su runtime propio

---

> Entiendo que publicarlo de esta manera, crea el ejecutable dentro de
> mi carpeta PruebaMVC en windows. Esto posteriormente quiero hacerlo en
> la maquina virtual.

Así es, también puedes copiar/pegar esos archivos a donde quieras

---

> Tenia entendido que ASP crea un servidor propio y podría correrlo
> independiente. O quizá sigo confundido

Así es, tal como te señalo en el primero punto.

El tema es: Tu aplicación tiene un servidor incluido, pero en esencia es una aplicación más, que se puede ejecutar con un doble click

IIS en cambio corre como servicio windows y los servicios tienen la peculiaridad que puede reiniciarse automáticamente cuando se caen. Aunque, a mi no me ha pasado nunca que la aplicación se caiga, ya que maneja las excepciones internamente, pero siempre existe la posibilidad

Además existen temas de administración cuando tienes varios sitios donde IIS facilita la vida y bueno muchos otros escenarios donde tener un servidor web es mejor solución que ejecutar directamente la aplicación

---

> Hacer HTML css y javascript o base de datos medianamente basico es
> tranquilo. Pero esto de la creacion de API, y controladores es
> terrible. Me encontré con una pared inmensa.

Bueno es opinable, yo me manejo bien en todas esas tecnologías y es bastante más simple y menos trabajo hacer una API. En visual studio se hace con una mano amarrada a la espalda

---

Tambien te puede interesar leer de esto nuevo que ha aparecido y relación con la publicación de proyectos [.NET Aspire](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/aspire-overview)

Comment: Perfecto. Si despues de publicar ayer, me puse a investigar, y me entere que kestrel viene integrado en ASP.NET. Me pondre mas en el tema para avanzar! Muchas gracias